# Error in executing npm start in Angular 4 with non standard global package installation location?

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular

I just started a new Angular 4 project, I executed npm start in the project directory and it gave error

"node_modules appears empty, you may need to run npm install"

[image: Error]

I wonder is it because I changed my npm and npm-cache installation location with this guide:

https://blog.jsinh.in/change-default-nodejs-npm-and-npm-cache-directory-on-windows/#.WWlyUOlLdPY

I changed the global installation location to

"D:\Program\Node.js\npm"

Or is it because of other reason ?